# How to input a specific value (lets say 1) in to particular columns in a dataframe wherein the column names are provided as a list?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

**There are two time series dataframes**,

I. "stock_rec" --> Has two columns --> 1) 'Date' - The date time index 2) 'Portfolio' - Contains the list of stocks in the portfolio for each date

II. "stock_matrix" --> Has 6 columns --> 1) 'Date' - The date time index 2 to 6) Stock1, Stock2, Stock3, Stock4 and Stock5. The dataframe is empty as of now

**Operation to be performed:** For every date, based on the list of stocks (Stock1,Stock2,Stock3,Stock4,Stock5) in the portfolio (Available in "stock_rec"), the particular cell in "stock_matrix" needs to be made 1.

**Expected Output** : Lets say for "Jan 2018" (the date index), the "stock_rec" indicates that ['Stock1','Stock4'] are in the portfolio. Then the values in the columns ['Stock1'] and ['Stock4'] in the dataframe "stock_matrix" for the date "Jan 2018", needs to be made 1

Input:

```html
stock_rec 
Date Portfolio
Jan-10 ['Stock 1','Stock 5']
Feb-10 ['Stock 2','Stock 5']
Mar-10 ['Stock 3','Stock 4','Stock 5]
Apr-10 ['Stock 1']
May-10 []

stock_matrix
Date Stock 1 Stock 2 Stock 3 Stock 4 Stock 5
Jan-10 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
Feb-10 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
Mar-10 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
Apr-10 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
May-10 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

Ouput:

```html
stock_matrix
Date Stock 1 Stock 2 Stock 3 Stock 4 Stock 5
Jan-10 1 NaN NaN NaN 1
Feb-10 NaN 1 NaN NaN 1
Mar-10 NaN NaN 1 1 1
Apr-10 1 NaN NaN NaN NaN
May-10 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

Comment: please provide example data and example output of that data.

Comment: Possibly something with `col.str.contains` and `np.where`, but as @MattW. stated, we need to see the data samples to make a [mcve] for your request

Comment: @Matt W and @ G. Anderson - Have added the example data and expected out

Comment: @ Matt W - Thanks. Have provided some comment on your post.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to unlist, or stack the series of lists

Taking a snippit of your dataframe and defining all the stocks we want:

```
stocks = ['Stock 1', 'Stock 2', 'Stock 3', 'Stock 4', 'Stock 5']

df = pd.DataFrame({'date':['Jan-10', 'Feb-10'], 'Portfolio':[['Stock 1', 'Stock 5', 'Stock 4'], ['Stock 2', 'Stock 5']]})
```

The first thing I'll do is I'll make a fake `"None"` field for the missing columns:

```
df['Portfolio'] = [['None'] if x == [] else x for x in df['Portfolio']]
```

Now we set the index as the date column, and then we grab just the series we want. We then apply each list as its own series and then stack them all one on top of the other. We then reset the index so that we get the date back into the dataframe. We drop the level_1 created, and rename the 0 column back to Portfolio. Lastly we create a new column with just 1s in it for later.

```
df = df.set_index('date').Portfolio.apply(pd.Series) \
        .stack() \
        .reset_index(drop=False) \
        .drop(['level_1'], axis=1) \
        .rename(columns={0:'Portfolio'}) \
        .assign(v=1)

     date Portfolio  v
0  Jan-10   Stock 1  1
1  Jan-10   Stock 5  1
2  Jan-10   Stock 4  1
3  Feb-10   Stock 2  1
4  Feb-10   Stock 5  1
```

Now we can just pivot this.

```
pd.pivot_table(df,
               columns='Portfolio',
               index='date',
               values='v') \
  .drop(['None'], axis=1)
```

Now we add in any that are missing from the stocks list:

```
missing_cols = np.array(stocks)[~pd.Series(stocks).isin(piv.columns)].tolist()   
for col in missing_cols:
    piv[col] = np.nan

Portfolio  Stock 1  Stock 2  Stock 4  Stock 5  Stock 3
date                                                  
Feb-10         NaN      1.0      NaN      1.0      NaN
Jan-10         1.0      NaN      1.0      1.0      NaN
Mar-10         NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
```

If you want the `NaN`s to be `0`s, you can pass the `fill_value=0` argument to the `pd.pivot_table()`

Comment: Thanks Matt, this is a very neat approach, the only issue is that this does not ensure that all the columns ("Stock 1" to "Stock 5") are there in the output, even if it is going to be "Nan", "Stock 3" column needs to be there in the output. Is there any way we can fix this in the code.

Comment: @AravindGanesan I just updated the code to fix for that. I just edited the beginning code to make a fake "Stock" called "None", and then just dropped it in the end. Also - I just realized you were calling out the missing Stock 3. I didn't include that in my beginning code. So if you have a starting point of all columns then I would add Nan columns in the end of where they are missing.

Comment: @AravindGanesan fixed the missing columns thing, though if its in your dataset at all it should show up for a date.